# Informatica Flat File source name

Tags: unix, etl, informatica, informatica-powercenter, flat-file

I am working on a project were we need to load flat file eg : (Gemstone_20220325.csv) I have given the source name as (Gemstone_*.csv) in script to search for the file in the path.

But it is failing with error , No such file .

Is that anything I am missing . Any idea on this is much appreciated .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to put either exact name or use a file list with the name of the file and then use indirect file type in the session that is reading the file.

1. You can use a pre session shell command like this `ls -1 Gemstone_*.csv>/infa/home/tmp/Gemstone_filelist.txt`. Or you can create a shell script too with this command for better control.
2. in the session that is reading this file, set the property to indirect file type and mention `/infa/home/tmp/Gemstone_filelist.txt` as file to be extracted.
   Infa will pick files one by one and process them.
3. Once the file gets processed, delete it using a post session command task `rm -f Gemstone_*.`.